# Check pandas for NaN and differing types

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In order to check, whether a pandas contains missing/nan values, one can use the [isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html#targetText=Detect%20missing%20values%20for%20an,arrays%2C%20NaT%20in%20datetimelike) function.

```
test_pandas = pd.DataFrame([[np.float(3),np.float(1),np.float(4.3)],[np.float(5.8),np.nan,[1,2,3]]],columns = ['A','B','C'])
value = test_pandas.isnull().values.any()
test_pandas.head()
```

gives

```
     A    B          C
0  3.0  1.0        4.3
1  5.8  NaN  [1, 2, 3]
```

and with

```
print("There exists a nan value in the dataframe: ",test_pandas.isnull().values.any())
print("Number of nan values: ",test_pandas.isnull().sum().sum())
```

we find

```
There exists a nan value in the dataframe:  True
Number of nan values:  1
```

- How do I check in the same way, wether there are values in a pandas dataframe, whose type is not 
  e.g. a float. I would like to detect, that there is an entry of type list among the float values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom function with [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
def isfloat(x):
    return isinstance(x, float)


print(df.applymap(isfloat))
```

**Output**

```
      A     B      C
0  True  True   True
1  True  True  False
```